# CUDA Array of Structs With Arrays (AoSoA)

Tags: c, arrays, struct, cuda, malloc

**Note 4**
*So the code is finally fixed! Turned out the final problem was that I was adding the size of the space allocated to each array to the ptr, but c already takes into account the size of the variable, so I was essentially adding 4x as much space in bytes as I should have been, hence only the first two elements in a 5-element array would display.  The `AoSoA` is now fully working.  Be careful with your mem. management if you try something similar, I struggled with a lot of seemingly silly errors because my initial code was sloppy.*

Beware:
+ Improper offsets
+ Needless malloc's
+ Out of range references

*Here's the working example code, results follow!*

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define REGIONS 20
#define YEARS 5

__inline __host__ void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, 
                 bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code),
          file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

struct AnimalPopulationForYear_s
{
   bool isYearEven;
   int * rabbits;
   int * hyenas;
};

AnimalPopulationForYear_s * dev_pop;

__global__ void RunSim(AnimalPopulationForYear_s dev_pop[],
               int year)
{
   int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
   int rabbits, hyenas;
   int arrEl = year-1;

   rabbits = (idx+1) * year * year; 
   hyenas = rabbits / 10;

   if ( rabbits > 100000 ) rabbits = 100000;   
   if ( hyenas < 2 ) hyenas = 2;

   if ( idx < REGIONS ) dev_pop[arrEl].rabbits[idx] = rabbits;
   if ( idx < REGIONS ) dev_pop[arrEl].hyenas[idx] = hyenas;

   if (threadIdx.x == 0 && blockIdx.x == 0)
      dev_pop[arrEl].isYearEven = (year & 0x01 == 0x0);
}

int main()
{
   //Various reused sizes...
   const size_t fullArrSz = size_t(YEARS) * size_t(REGIONS) * sizeof(int);
   const size_t structArrSz = size_t(YEARS) * sizeof(AnimalPopulationForYear_s);

   //Vars to hold struct and merged subarray memory inside it.
   AnimalPopulationForYear_s * h_pop;
   int * dev_hyenas, * dev_rabbits, * h_hyenas, * h_rabbits, arrEl;

   //Alloc. memory.
   h_pop = (AnimalPopulationForYear_s *) malloc(structArrSz);
   h_rabbits = (int *) malloc(fullArrSz);
   h_hyenas = (int *) malloc(fullArrSz);
   gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_pop,structArrSz));
   gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_rabbits,fullArrSz));
   gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_hyenas,fullArrSz));

   //Offset ptrs.
   for (int i = 0; i < YEARS; i++)
   {
      h_pop[i].rabbits = dev_rabbits+i*REGIONS;
      h_pop[i].hyenas = dev_hyenas+i*REGIONS;
   }

   //Copy host struct with dev. pointers to device.
   gpuErrchk
      (cudaMemcpy(dev_pop,h_pop, structArrSz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

   //Call kernel
   for(int i=1; i < YEARS+1; i++) RunSim<<<REGIONS/128+1,128>>>(dev_pop,i);

   //Make sure nothing went wrong.
   gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
   gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

   gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_pop,dev_pop,structArrSz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
   gpuErrchk
      (cudaMemcpy(h_rabbits, dev_rabbits,fullArrSz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
   gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_hyenas,dev_hyenas,fullArrSz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

   for(int i=0; i < YEARS; i++)
   {
      h_pop[i].rabbits = h_rabbits + i*REGIONS;
      h_pop[i].hyenas = h_hyenas + i*REGIONS;
   }

   for(int i=1; i < YEARS+1; i++)
   {
      arrEl = i-1;
      printf("\nYear %i\n=============\n\n", i);      
      printf("Rabbits\n-------------\n");
      for (int j=0; j < REGIONS; j++)
     printf("Region: %i  Pop: %i\n", j, h_pop[arrEl].rabbits[j]);;      
      printf("Hyenas\n-------------\n");
      for (int j=0; j < REGIONS; j++)
     printf("Region: %i  Pop: %i\n", j, h_pop[arrEl].hyenas[j]);
   }

   //Free on device and host
   cudaFree(dev_pop);
   cudaFree(dev_rabbits);
   cudaFree(dev_hyenas);

   free(h_pop);
   free(h_rabbits);
   free(h_hyenas);

   return 0;
}
```

[Finally] correct results:

> Year 1
>   =============
>  
>  Rabbits
>   -------------
>  Region: 0  Pop: 1
>  Region: 1  Pop: 2
>  Region: 2  Pop: 3
>  Region: 3  Pop: 4
>  Region: 4  Pop: 5
>   Region: 5  Pop: 6
>  Region: 6  Pop: 7
>  Region: 7  Pop: 8
>   Region: 8  Pop: 9
>  Region: 9  Pop: 10
>  Region: 10  Pop:
>   11
>  Region: 11  Pop: 12
>  Region: 12  Pop: 13
>  Region: 13 
>   Pop: 14
>  Region: 14  Pop: 15
>  Region: 15  Pop: 16
>  Region:
>   16  Pop: 17
>  Region: 17  Pop: 18
>  Region: 18  Pop: 19
>   Region: 19  Pop: 20
>  Hyenas
>   -------------
>  Region: 0  Pop: 2
>  Region: 1  Pop: 2
>  Region: 2  Pop: 2
>  Region: 3  Pop: 2
>  Region: 4  Pop: 2
>   Region: 5  Pop: 2
>  Region: 6  Pop: 2
>  Region: 7  Pop: 2
>   Region: 8  Pop: 2
>  Region: 9  Pop: 2
>  Region: 10  Pop: 2
>   Region: 11  Pop: 2
>  Region: 12  Pop: 2
>  Region: 13  Pop:
>   2
>  Region: 14  Pop: 2
>  Region: 15  Pop: 2
>  Region: 16 
>   Pop: 2
>  Region: 17  Pop: 2
>  Region: 18  Pop: 2
>  Region: 19
>   Pop: 2
>  
>  Year 2
>   =============
>  
>  Rabbits
>   -------------
>  Region: 0  Pop: 4
>  Region: 1  Pop: 8
>  Region: 2  Pop: 12
>  Region: 3  Pop: 16
>  Region: 4  Pop:
>   20
>  Region: 5  Pop: 24
>  Region: 6  Pop: 28
>  Region: 7 
>   Pop: 32
>  Region: 8  Pop: 36
>  Region: 9  Pop: 40
>  Region:
>   10  Pop: 44
>  Region: 11  Pop: 48
>  Region: 12  Pop: 52
>   Region: 13  Pop: 56
>  Region: 14  Pop: 60
>  Region: 15  Pop:
>   64
>  Region: 16  Pop: 68
>  Region: 17  Pop: 72
>  Region: 18 
>   Pop: 76
>  Region: 19  Pop: 80
>  Hyenas
>   -------------
>  Region: 0  Pop: 2
>  Region: 1  Pop: 2
>  Region: 2  Pop: 2
>  Region: 3  Pop: 2
>  Region: 4  Pop: 2
>   Region: 5  Pop: 2
>  Region: 6  Pop: 2
>  Region: 7  Pop: 3
>   Region: 8  Pop: 3
>  Region: 9  Pop: 4
>  Region: 10  Pop: 4
>   Region: 11  Pop: 4
>  Region: 12  Pop: 5
>  Region: 13  Pop:
>   5
>  Region: 14  Pop: 6
>  Region: 15  Pop: 6
>  Region: 16 
>   Pop: 6
>  Region: 17  Pop: 7
>  Region: 18  Pop: 7
>  Region: 19
>       ...

**Note 3:**
*Following [talonmies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies) cleaned up multiple array indexing inconsistencies, etc. in my code.*

*The results get seeming the correct SoA for the first two spots in the AoSoA (see new output).  For some reason the results from the third spot (`year 3`) on are now giving wrong results, although there's no error code from the GPU.  I'm going to peek at the pointers (`h_pop[year-1].rabbits`,`h_pop[year-1].hyenas`) and see if that reveals anything.*

*My only advice for anyone else attempting AoSoA -- be VERY careful with your indexing, and memory allocation.  Of course that's good advice in general, but with all the memory flying around in a complex multi-level data container such as the AoSoA, the tendency for error if you're sloppy exponentially increases.  Thanks for your patience, [talonmies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies).*

**Note 2:**
*So following the advice of [talonmies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies), I fixed my loop #ing, wrapped my cuda calls w. the error checking and condensed my `cudaMemcpy` calls by reusing `dev_rabbits`/`dev_hyenas`.  Also switched the case to be lowercased on the first letter, as I was thinking about [djmj][4]'s complaint about casing and I realized that NVIDIA does lowercase the first letter in their constants, so [djmj][4] was right, in a sense, I should have styled my code like that for consistency, regardless of my personal preferences/experience.*

*Also generally cleaned up the code, as I wrote it going on not much sleep and was kinda horrified @ how sloppy it was.*

*Now I'm running into a new issue, though... my program hangs @ the first `cudaMemcpy`, and does not return (hence [talonmies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies)'s handy wrapper does not catch anything).  I'm not quite sure why this is... I've compiled several programs, including much larger/longer-running ones on the device, and they all work fine.*

*At this point I'm puzzled.  If it's still not working, might post something in the morning.*

**Note 1**
*The first answer seemed to really miss the point.  This is just a toy code, it's not meant to represent a real program.  Its sole purpose is try to set up the memory, write some junk to it and read it back, in order to verify AoSoA is working.*

*So commenting to me on shared memory, etc. is not going to be productive.  That's not the point of this thread.  Of course if this was a real code I'd be eliminating branching in my kernels, using shared memory, aligning my data, using warp level summation, etc.  I've done all that in past codes and got it working.*

*This code is toy, proof of concept code, nothing more, nothing less, designed to try to get AoSoA working.  That is its only purpose, it is not a real code.  it is a proof of concept.*

*As for the casing of the var names, I worked at two different places that used fully cased var names in their coding standard (they used tags, I do `_s` on structs/typedefs), so it kind of stuck.  Sorry you don't like it.  As for the indentation I'll try to fix that later... Windows and Linux were not playing nicely.*

*One more note, if you're confused by the device pointer offsetting, see [Anycom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206328/anycorn)'s answer here:

[Pointers in structs passed to CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289554/pointers-in-structs-passed-to-cuda)*

I wrote the following code to test arrays of structures with arrays inside in CUDA....

*Edit: Fixed code -- hangs after `meh` and before `hi`, presumably on the `cudaMemcpy`... unsure why!*

...Any idea what's going on here and how to fix it?

**Note:**
I was worried the `cudaFree`s might be screwing things up, but removing them did nothing.
[4]:

Comment: Is this homework? It's kind of an odd indentation scheme you have. I would suggest using regular indentation and also to use curly brackets around even single statement blocks. I don't think __syncthreads() does any good where you have it, because the kernel has already stored its results at that point.

Comment: No, it's play-code for a research project.  Just trying to verify concepts using simple ambiguous code, then scaling up... the indent came from the transition between eMacs and NotePad++ screwing something up.... apologies for that.  Any ideas about the problem, though?

Comment: If no one has answered in around 6 hours or so, I'll run it locally and take a closer look. Let me know if you figure it out before then...

Comment: Great, thanks! I know I could do this with a flattened single struct, but addressing is much cleaner if I can somehow pull of the nesting..

Comment: You need to put some error checking into that code. Every API call returns a status. Check them all. It is very likely that your kernel is never running to completion and you are just looking at uninitialized memory.

Comment: @JasonR.Mick: I really don't understand. You have now replaced code in your original version which was 100% correct with a new version which is seriously wrong _and_ you haven't addressed the basic problem, which is a simple 1-indexing versus 0-indexing fault in your kernel, while at the breaking the kernel in a new way as well.

Comment: @Talonmies, uggh you're right... I put the `arrEl` offset to everything except the kernel call.  I'll add that to the logic in the kernel.  Do you see anything else wrong, though? Cheers,

Comment: Alright, turns out my offsetting was junk fixed... everything is now working.  Thank you so much for all your help, talonmies, now on to the real code... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an awful lot wrong with this code, but the basic cause of the "garbled" results you are asking about is that you are looking at uninitialized memory. `dev_Pop[0].Rabbits` is never set to anything in device memory, so you shouldn't be too surprised that its contents are "garbled". The root cause of the problem is this:

```
for(int i=1; i < YEARS+1; i++)
    RunSim<<<REGIONS/128+1,128>>>(dev_Pop,i);
```

Here you are starting from `year=1`, meaning `year=0` is never set to anything, and `year=YEARS` is a guaranteed buffer overflow in device memory.

Later in the copy back code, you do this at every iteration:

```
cudaFree(h_Pop[i].Rabbits);
cudaFree(h_Pop[i].Hyenas);
```

but your never malloced them in the first place, so the copy back operation will probably fail as well. How it will fail is hard to say without compiling and running the code, but I would *guess* that the CUDA runtime will completely free `dev_Rabbits` and `dev_Hyenas` on the first call. That should make subsequent `cudaMemcpy` calls in the loop fail. Irrespective of the precise mechanics, I would be incredibly surprised if your copy back loop successfully gets all the data back to the host. A much more sane implementation would be a work-alike of the code you used to construct the device memory image in the first place, something like:

```
const size_t dsize = size_t(YEARS) * size_t(REGIONS) * sizeof(int);
int * Rabbits = (int *) malloc(dsize);
int * Hyenas = (int *) malloc(dsize);
cudaMemcpy(Rabbits, dev_Rabbits, dsize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(Hyenas, dev_Hyenas, dsize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

for(int i=0; i < YEARS; i++)
{
    h_Pop[i].Rabbits = Rabbits + i*REGIONS;
    h_Pop[i].Hyenas = Hyenas + i*REGIONS;
}
```

Doing this way gets rid of a lot of redundant device->host transactions over the PCI-e bus, and all those unnecessary host side `malloc` calls within the loop.

So I would guess that there are multiple points of runtime failure happening in the code, but because you have neglected to include *any* error checking, things are silently failing and you just don't notice. To fix that add something like this in your code:

```
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char * file, int line, bool Abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code),file,line);
        if (Abort) exit(code);
    }       
}

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
```

and then used `gpuErrchk` to test the return status of *every* API call, for example:

```
gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_Pop,YEARS*sizeof(AnimalPopulationForYear_s)));
```

For your kernel launches, I recommend doing this:

```
RunSim<<<REGIONS/128+1,128>>>(dev_Pop,i);
gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
```

That will trap both illegal arguments and resource exhaustion which would cause a launch failure, and any execution errors which would cause a kernel abort. Armed with this error checking, I suspect you will find a lot of holes to fix before the code actually runs to completion....

---

**EDIT:**

It seems you have decided to invent new and unusual ways for your revised code to not work - including breaking the very thing that you had correct in your original code and seemed to be the subject of your question - the construction of a device memory array of structures.

Here is a slightly simplified and working version of your second code. All I can suggest is study it until you see why it works where your current version fails.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#define REGIONS 20
#define YEARS 5
#define POPMIN 2
#define POPMAX 100000

inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, 
                 bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code),
          file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

struct Population_s
{
   int * rabbits;
   int * hyenas;
};

__global__ void RunSim(Population_s * dev_pop, int year)
{
   int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;

   if (idx < REGIONS) {
      int rabbits, hyenas;

      rabbits = min(POPMAX, idx * year * year); 
      hyenas = max(POPMIN, rabbits / 10);

      dev_pop[year-1].rabbits[idx] = rabbits;
      dev_pop[year-1].hyenas[idx] = hyenas;
   }
}

int main()
{
   const size_t subArrSz = size_t(REGIONS) * sizeof(int);
   const size_t fullArrSz = size_t(YEARS) * subArrSz;
   const size_t structArrSz = size_t(YEARS) * sizeof(Population_s);

   Population_s * h_pop = (Population_s *) malloc(structArrSz);
   int * h_rabbits = (int *) malloc(fullArrSz);
   int * h_hyenas = (int *) malloc(fullArrSz);

   Population_s * dev_pop;
   int * dev_hyenas, * dev_rabbits;

   gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_pop,structArrSz));
   gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_hyenas,fullArrSz));
   gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void **) &dev_rabbits,fullArrSz));

   gpuErrchk(cudaMemset(dev_rabbits, 1, fullArrSz));
   gpuErrchk(cudaMemset(dev_hyenas, 1, fullArrSz));

   for (int i = 0; i < YEARS; i++)
   {
      h_pop[i].rabbits = dev_rabbits + i*REGIONS;
      h_pop[i].hyenas = dev_hyenas + i*REGIONS;
   }

   gpuErrchk
      (cudaMemcpy(dev_pop,h_pop, structArrSz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

   for(int i = 1; i < (YEARS+1); i++) {
       RunSim<<<REGIONS/128+1,128>>>(dev_pop,i);
       gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
       gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
   }

   gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_rabbits, dev_rabbits, fullArrSz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
   gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_hyenas, dev_hyenas, fullArrSz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

   for(int i=0; i < YEARS; i++)
   {
      h_pop[i].rabbits = h_rabbits + i*REGIONS;
      h_pop[i].hyenas = h_hyenas + i*REGIONS;
   }

   for(int i=0; i < YEARS; i++)
   {
      printf("\n=============\n");   
      printf("Year %i\n=============\n\n", i+1);   
      printf("Rabbits\n-------------\n", i);
      for (int j=0; j < REGIONS; j++)
         printf("Region: %i  Pop: %i\n", j, h_pop[i].rabbits[j]);;      
      printf("\nHyenas\n-------------\n", i);
      for (int j=0; j < REGIONS; j++)
         printf("Region: %i  Pop: %i\n", j, h_pop[i].hyenas[j]);
   }

   cudaFree(dev_pop);
   cudaFree(dev_rabbits);
   cudaFree(dev_hyenas);

   free(h_pop);
   free(h_rabbits);
   free(h_hyenas);

   return 0;
}
```

As a final tip - *don't* use anything from the SDK `cutil` library in your own code, that isn't what it is intended for. It isn't an official part of CUDA, doesn't have documentation, isn't considered production ready, and isn't guaranteed to either work, be the same, or even exist in any given release of the CUDA SDK.

Comment: oh damn did not find that, that with the output loop starting at 0, for(int i=0; i < YEARS; i++) is the point. But the data is allocated using the loop block below the commented block. That is a nice way to create multi-dimensional pointers. Saves that malloc loop. Did not knew this before.

Comment: @djmj: On your last remark, I think you misunderstood. There is a golden rule in C: "never explicitly free something your code didn't explicitly allocate". The code explicitly allocates `dev_Rabbits` and `dev_Hyendas` with a cudaMalloc call, not what each `h_Pop[i].Rabbits` and `h_Pop[i].Hyenas` points to. `cudaFree` must be called on `dev_Rabbits` and `dev_Hyendas` __once__, not the way it is done now.

Comment: Thanks for that info. What I meant was that the needed memory for the kernel is allocated but I should go to sleep for today before I post more irrelevant stuff.

Comment: Thanks talonmies, will recompile with error trapping and let you know the results.

Comment: Okay, cleaned up the code (see above), but it's hanging on the first cudaMemcpy and not returning, hence not getting to your wrapper.  It wasn't doing this with the old code, but again, the old code was kinda whacky and needed to be cleaned up.  I tried running a much longer (real) program of mine that approaches near full utilization of the device and it ran just fine, so I'm not sure why it's hanging.

Comment: @JasonR.Mick: The first  `cudaMemcpy` isn't hanging. The nice endless loop you have written is.

Comment: Ahh right... decrement is changing the actual value... duh... wow.

Comment: So, I fixed that and now I'm getting "Unspecified launch failure" on the Cuda synchronize call... interesting.

Comment: Sounds like that's the GPU's std. segfaultish response... better double check all my logic.

Comment: okay cleaned up a whole bunch of stuff.  Sorry for the sloppy code & thanks for your patience & continued help.  Anyhow, it's now getting the correct results for the first 2 (!) (weird, I know?) spots, but not the rest... I'm sure it's just one last sloppy error.  But at least I see the first two SoAs appearing with the correct, proper results in the AoSoA!!  Yay!! You were extremely helpful... I'll be sure to uprate every single comment you left @ least. :)

Comment: PS. If you could vote this up to 0 that would be appreciated... other people do seem to be searching for how to do AoSoA (based on posts to the NVIDIA dev forums), and this should help them.

Comment: @JasonR.Mick: I only vote up what I consider to be good questions, and unfortunately this isn't one of those. It is way too localized to really ever be of benefit to anyone except you. It degenerated into what is only a slightly better version of "why doesn't my code work, please help kthankxbai" and the effort expended on answering it was mostly chasing down bugs from poor programming practices rather than anything to do with the original question about memory management of arrays of structures.